# Inequality with gcds

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Prove that $gcd(a,b-1)gcd(b,c-1)gcd(c,a-1)\le ab+bc+ac-a-b-c+1$.
I can't even find when the equality stands except for one trivial case, and the task also asks us to prove that there are infinitely many $(a,b,c)$ which satisfy the equality.
Also we can notice that if the equality is satisfied, every $p$ where $p|a =>p|(b-1)(c-1)$, and same for $b$ and $c$, also if $p|a-1 =>$ $p|bc$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ It suffices to show the LHS divides the RHS. Let $\,d = \gcd(a,b-1).\,$ Then $\,d\mid a,b-1$ so $\,{\rm mod}\ d\!:\ \color{#c00}{a\equiv 0},\, \color{#0a0}{b\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, e = \color{#c00}ab+\color{#0a0}bc+\color{#c00}ac-\color{#c00}a-\color{#0a0}b-c+1 \equiv c-1-c+1\equiv 0.\,$ Thus $\,d\mid e.\,$ Similarly for the others (by symmetry). Finally, the lcm of the gcds is their product since they are pairwise coprime, since for any pair of gcds, one divides $\,n,\,$ the other $\,n\!-\!1,\,$ for $\,n\in \{a,b,c\}.\,$ Therefore since each gcd divides $\,e\,$ so too does their lcm = product.

Alternatively, notice that $\ e\, =\, abc + (1-a)(1-b)(1-c),\, $ which makes the divisibility clear.

The proof shows $\,(a,b')(b,c')(c,a')\mid abc+a'b'c'\ $ if  $\ (a,a'),(b,b'),(c,c')\,$ are all $\,1$